# How do I get WiX Burn install to reboot with MSI?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, reboot

I am creating a [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) installer for dependencies and my application, but I need to reboot once my application is installed, before running part 2 of the installer.

I have found how to do this with an ExePackage, but not an MSIPackage. How can I make Wix reboot after one MSI install and then continue on with the next? Just scheduling a reboot in the MSI doesn't do the trick.

Comment: <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" /> ?

Comment: Thats only available for ExePackages, not MsiPackage in WIX, i dont know why its not supported, it seems like a fairly useful thing to have all round!

Comment: The MSI can't force a reboot if required? Also, why is the reboot necessary? In many cases the reason can be eliminated.

Comment: @PhilDW you raise a fair point, late yesterday I found my custom actions werent performing as expected, which meant that my assumptions about why i needed the reboot in the first place were wrong. I removed the need for the installer to force reboot, and now just reboot as it changes the system name (its a controlled environment on a larger system.. so changing system is aok!) Thanks for the feedback and assistance.